# A Selenium test passes when run individually, hangs when run in a suite, and amazingly passes in the suite when logging is enabled or run remotely

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

Inconsistency is the theme here. I have a large Selenium test suite that is giving me issues on a Mac. My coworkers use Windows and they are not experiencing any problems with it. Essentially when I run the whole suite using TestNG, the tests behave differently than when run individually. Individually, the tests complete without any problems. When run as a whole suite, currently about ten tests, the third test to be executed always hangs at the exact same spot. It tries to find an element and never comes out of the Selenium API. The point of no return is marked with the `XXX` below.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
try {
    element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathLocator));  // XXX
} catch (NoSuchElementException | org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException e)
```

The suite is not being run in parallel. The same behavior is occurring across Chrome, Firefox, and Safari although the element that is being sought when the program hangs does change between browsers. I'm currently using *Mac 10.10.6* with the latest versions of Selenium, Eclipse, and TestNG. The same behavior is occurring on separate Mac machines. The behavior is also the same whether I run the TestNG suite in Eclipse or from the command line. The entire suite is executed without any problems when logging is enabled on the node via `-log someFile` or when the node is running on a remote machine i.e. not locally. The suite is fairly large so if there's any other code I can post here that would be helpful in diagnosing the issue please let me know. Any ideas to point me in the right direction would be very helpful.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? It sounds like something like that could actually help.

Comment: I would try this: 1) insert a logger before finding element (save viewport screenshot and raw html) 2) run test alone 3) run whole suite 4) compare screenshot and raw html between successful and failed test results of the same test. 5) figure out what's going on ;-)

Comment: Trick: Run with firebug add on and run your suite in debug mode. just before the element is to be found stop there and chk in firebug for the presence of element? if the element appears with the locator that you are using (which i doubt) then issue is something else, Else you found out the issue :)

Comment: `...although the element that is being sought when the program hangs does change between browsers` could you elaborate,just to clear.

Comment: @nullpointer Imagine we run the suite only in Chrome. There's an anchor element on some page. The XPath of that anchor element is what is being passed into `findElement()` when execution hangs there. Kill the program, run it again in Chrome. Execution hangs again. That same anchor is what is being passed into `findElement()` when the program hangs. Kill the program, run the suite on Firefox. It will still hang at `findElement()`, but the XPath being passed in will be different than our anchor tag in Chrome.

Comment: @zapl Yes unfortunately, no such luck.

Comment: @drets The problem is the program makes it deep into the Selenium API so the logger at the step you are referring will not help us.

Comment: just to ensure, does this Xpath has any dynamically generated element?
cause xpath of its uncertainity is not used anyway to access elements..

Comment: @nullpointer Good point but no it is not dynamically generated.

Comment: @Steve Then just to assure you have the element on the web page where you want it. Before you find the element, try `String everything = driver.getPageSource()` and look if it contains your  `xpathLocator` or not?

Comment: It surely feels like communication problem, and not just element not found problem.
I would investigate 3 directions: 
1. When running from TestNG you are either reusing browser instance / driver instance or not closing previous instance completely, or too fast. That one should be easy to check (i.e. make sure both browser and driver go away completely after each test run). Of course it may not be a viable solution to close browser and driver every time, but at least you will identify the issue

Comment: 2. Something happens in communication between selenium clinet and driver or driver and browser. You could check by sniffing network (e.g. with Fiddle, or Wireshark)
3. Some JS on the page is causing it. Difficult to debug (e.g. disable some JS? change some versions? very much depends on the page).

Comment: @KirilS. That is my hunch as well. I'll try your recommendations. Thank you!

Comment: @Steve While running on remote machine does this particular test case fail ? And does it continue smoothly because the connections is terminated after certain time by the hub for non responding browsers?

Comment: @Shamik While the node is running on a remote machine, the test passes. The is able to run smoothly while still maintaining an active connection to the hub.

Comment: What if you'll use REAL Selenium way, something like `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpathLocator)));` ?

Comment: Can you define "hangs"? Up to how long have you waited? Several minutes? Overnight?

Comment: Some ideas:
 1. make sure you're using the latest version of selenium-webdriver
 2. try `driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` (I doubt this it as I don't _think_ findElement uses a script but I'm not sure)
 3. create a smaller test suite to reproduce the problem (you can create some static HTML file(s) to use, etc.) and then post it
 4. if permissible, zip archive your code and post it somewhere for others to download and take a deeper look at, etc.

Comment: @Steve How do you handle exception at `catch` block?

Comment: @nazar_art Execution doesn't reach the `catch` block so that shouldn't matter.

Comment: @mfulton26 "hangs" meaning execution stops indefinitely like it's in an infinite loop.

Comment: @Stanjer That is an explicit wait which is completely different from what I'm using, an implicit wait.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Placing timeouts and wait's are inherently subjective since the time a page takes to load can vary. The best thing you can do is place it in a while loop, but include a large timeout to force the code out of the while loop, or throw an error if the element cannot be found since it is a test after all.

```
 int i = 0;                        
  while (!driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathLocator))
    {
    //timeout goes here
    i++;
    if (i == 10) throw new exception
}
```

something like this should do the trick

Comment: for an even more compact version, one could use the `for` loop instead

Comment: I will accept this since it is the best complete answer provided. However this does not solve the core of the issue. Are you recommending to not use Implicit or Explicit waits? What method would you use as a timeout?

Comment: @Steve, If you are using Selenium2 there is a WebDriverWait class that may be more useful to you.     `var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
            return wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(by));`

Comment: @bilpor That is an Explicit wait mate.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should increase implicitlyWait from '0'.

I heard there are some HTML loading issues in Mac. By increasing the time value, it will solve DOM loading issues.

Selenium Document says this about implicitlyWait.

Implicit Waits
An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available. The default setting is 0. Once set, the implicit wait is set for the life of the WebDriver object instanc